# Growing mdadm raid1 live; metadata 1.1 and 1.2

Tags: mdadm

I can find a lot of posts about growing a mdadm RAID1 array on a live system. After growing the partitions, everybody simply says to do:

```
mdadm --grow /dev/md1 --size=max
```

But that doesn't work, because the size of the component is stored in the meta data (`mdadm --examine` shows this). Did this work at some point? The man page says the following, implying live growing used to work, but no longer:

> The devicesize will rarely be of use.  It applies to version 1.1 and
>   1.2 metadata only (where the metadata  is  at  the  start  of  the device)  and  is  only useful when the component device has changed
>   size (typically become larger). The version 1 metadata records the
>   amount of the device that can be used to store data, so if a device in
>   a version 1.1 or 1.2 array becomes  larger,  the  metadata  will still
>   be visible, but the extra space will not. In this case it might be
>   useful to assemble the array with --update=devicesize. This will cause
>   mdadm to determine the maximum usable amount of space on each device
>   and update the relevant field in the metadata.

So with the *newer* superblock version, live growing is just not possible anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, I was indeed able to grow the array by assembling it from a live CD with parameter `--update=devicesize`. Unfortunately, though, I don't remember the exact command.